# Working with git branches on vagrant

Tags: git, vagrant

I have a local repository, which has a vagrant setup. After setting it up, I want to go about changing the code of that repository. For that I am planning to have a new git branch. How is it possible to work, on the local repository and make it work on the vagrant machine? I think that `vagrant push` is the option, but I am not sure.

Comment: your local repo is shared with your `/vagrant` directory in the VM, so no need to run any command - its automatic

Comment: Is it updated automatically, or is there any command for that?

Comment: it is updated automatically unless you have rsync shared folder. you should put your Vagrantfile in the op

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Frédéric Henri has stated in his comments, the code is updated automatically with the vagrant machine. Also the git branches work seamlessly.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that git commands are usually available both from your host machine as well as from within you VM, though global git settings from these two are different (not shared at all). Therefore the result of the same commands may differ.